# What is the best way of storing image in mysql db

Tags: mysql

What is the best way to store image in mysql db. Whether I can store using blob data type or just insert image url. Also any performance difference is there when storing image using blob or image url?

Comment: i guess better to store base64 encoded string,

Comment: I know people who swear by blobs and people who swear by URLs. There's advantages and disadvantages to both. There's no right answer here so just do whichever better fits your setup.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't store your image in a blob or anything.
Save the images somewhere on disk, with a reference to the image location in the database. 
This way it is a lot more flexible and your database size stays small.

(Assuming that you're using it for a website) it is also faster, since it reduces database requests. If you store the image as a blob the browser would send a http-request for each image, each resulting in a query to the database. When storing it on disk the webserver handles it directly (as a static file) without the need to request the database, so you'd  have the advantage of Nginx (if using it) being able to handle static files fast.

Comment: Since this is tagged as just MySQL its worth noting there's no way to check if the image exists or has been moved just using MySQL. Some data integrity checks will have to be moved outside of the database, which some people would say is a real pain. I would recommend if one is to save an image to disk, to rename it based on the hash of the database row key to do some basic validation that way.